Given a sequence $(a_n)$, determine whether $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence if $|a_n - a_{n+1}|\leq \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{3/2 +n}}$
Given a sequence $(a_n)$, I need to determine whether $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. It is provided that for all $(n)$, the sequence satisfies the condition:
$$|a_n - a_{n+1}|\leq \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{3/2 +n}}.$$
My Analysis:
To analyze this, observe that the numerator $(n+1)^n$ grows asymptotically like $(n^n)$ for large $(n)$. The denominator can be expressed as:
$$
n^{3/2 + n} = n^n \cdot n^{3/2}.
$$
For large $(n)$, this allows us to simplify the given bound:
$$|a_n - a_{n+1}| \leq \frac{n^n}{n^n \cdot n^{3/2}} = \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}.$$
Since the difference between consecutive terms decays as $(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}})$, we can infer that the sum of these differences converges, because the series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$
is convergent (as the exponent (3/2 > 1)).
Conclusion:
The convergence of the series $(\sum \frac{1}{n^{3/2}})$ gives us strong intuition that the sequence ((a_n)) is Cauchy. However, while this provides a good heuristic, I am struggling to rigorously prove that the sequence satisfies the Cauchy criterion. Could you provide guidance on how to formally establish this?

$$| a_{n+1}-a_n|\leq \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{3/2+n}}=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}<\frac{e}{n^{3/2}},\quad n\in\mathbb N.$$
Since the seires
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e}{n^{3/2}}$$
is convergent, for any given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$, sunch that when $n>N$, we have
$$\frac{e}{n^{3/2}}+\cdots+\frac{e}{(n+p-1)^{3/2}}<\epsilon,\quad p\in\mathbb N.$$
So
$$|x_{n+p}-x_n|\leq|x_{n+p}-x_{n+p-1}|+\cdots+|x_{n+1}-x_n|\\
<\frac{e}{(n+p-1)^{3/2}}+\cdots+\frac{e}{n^{3/2}}<\epsilon,\quad p\in\mathbb N.$$
Hence, $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy sequences.

Thank you so much for the answer.  My approach is acceptable or it has flaws?

@Srijan your idea is right, but need more details to prove.

Assuming $m>n$
$$|a_{m}-a_{n}|\leq |a_{m}-a_{m-1}| + ....+|a_{n+1}-a_{n}|\leq \sum_n^m\frac{(k+1)^2}{k^{1.5+k}}$$
So proving that $\sum\frac{(k+1)^2}{k^{1.5+k}}$ converges (hence is Cauchy) proves that $a_n$ is Cauchy.

Thank you so much.
